# sich bewerben darum, dass / sich bewerben darum + Inf-K

Tags: meaning, verb, meaning-in-context

I am reading a grammar; *sich bewerben* asks for the preposition *um* plus Akkusativ. *"Er bewirbt sich um ein Stipendium."* It is written that *"sich bewerben um"* can be constructed with a Nebensatz: a verbal Nebensatz introduced by *dass* or an infinitive construct.

Could you give an example of such a construction?

We can say *"Er bewirbt sich um ein Stipendium / eine Stelle."*
Can we say *"Er bewirbt sich darum, Koch zu werden"?*

Do you have any example with *"sich bewerben darum, dass"* and what meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Er bewirbt sich darum, eine Stelle als Koch anzutreten.

> Er bewirbt sich darum, ein Stipendium von der Frank-Zappa-Stiftung zu erhalten.

Die Konstruktion

> Er bewirbt sich darum, Koch zu werden.

klingt in meinen nicht ganz sauber, denn wenn die Bewerbung gelingt ist er ja noch nicht Koch, sondern hat nur eine Stelle, die geeignet ist, Koch werden zu können. Man würde jedoch verstehen, was gemeint ist und muss damit rechnen, ähnliches auch zu lesen.

> Er wetteifert darum, Schützenkönig zu werden.

geht dagegen problemlos - es ist also von der Semantik abhängig.

Answer (score 0):

An example with *dass*:

> Er bewirbt sich darum, dass er als Koch angestellt wird.

This is somewaht unelegant compared with *Er bewirbt sich darum, als Koch angestellt zu werden* or *Er bewirbt sich um eine Anstellung als Koch* but it is correct German.